MobaXterm configuration with Windows variables
I was trying to configure the MobaXterm configurations to different hosts and was trying to use windows variables inside the host configuration.
Unfortunatly it doesn't seem to work properly and seems to not resolute to the correct variable and I'm not extactly sure why.
e.g. I have a windows variable set to "2FAUSER" and the normal "USERNAME"
and try to configure it to use  it something like
%USERNAME%@%2FAUSER%%ldaphost@remotehost@2fahost

Config file looks afterwards something like this:
__PERCENT__USERNAME__PERCENT__@__PERCENT__2FAUSER__PERCENT__...

generally everything works if I just use the names without using the variables but trying to use variables seems to not resolute it correctly.
Unfortunatly I'm not sure how to exactly debug mobaxterm to see what's not working.
Is there a possibility to user windows variables in the host path or debug what is exactly not working?
Or is there a general better way to go around using specific names without actually typing a fixed name in the host path e.g. with specific username function of moba?

What you are referring to here is not automatic to an application.  The application would need to call ExpandEnviornmentStrings() on the field.  It does not and appears to support it's own syntax I would guess.

So solution would be working with a script which pulls the most recent config file and adjusts these variables via that then - so can't use a life shared config file with other people, hmm.

I like your thinking! :)  How about a script that adjusts the config file on each fire?  Script->update config->launch moba.. ?  "CAN'T USE"  ?? .. You are already coming to a solution I think.. even if it is a little ugly.  If you code, this would be a piece of cake in c#.. but probably just about anything.

Oh.. and MobaXTerm fan BIGTIME.  No other app like it.  Not even on *nix.
